# Prove the number is 7?

Tags: logic

Logic professor Ackermann to undergrads Beatrice and Carl, who both earned As in Algebra 2 back in their high-school careers:  “In this sealed envelope is a lone piece of paper upon which, in secret before coming here to meet you two, I wrote down a natural number between one and nine, inclusive.  At the moment, then, only one person on the planet knows what number is written inside the envelope, and that person is me."

Beatrice and Carl in unison:  “Understood, Dr Ackermann."

Ackermann:  “Okay, now, I will give you some statements from which to deduce, and let’s see who’s quicker on the draw regarding what can be proved from these statements regarding my hidden number.  Okay?”

In unison again, Beatrice and Carl:  “Understood.”

Ackermann:  “Very well; here we go.  Statement one:  My number is less than nine, and greater than one.  Statement two:  If the number is two, I didn’t write a number down.  Statement three:  There is nothing which is such that, if it’s a number I wrote down, everything is a number I wrote down.”

Carl is silent and sports, alas, a thoroughly vacant expression.  But Beatrice, smiling triumphantly, says:  “I can prove that the number you wrote down is seven!”  She promptly walks to the blackboard and begins writing ...

In a few minutes, Beatrice delivers on her promise:  the valid proof she writes out provokes a nod from Ackermann.  (Carl gives a grudging nod of his own, because while he can't quite wrap his head around the proof, he does realize that Beatrice has made use of reasoning that was explicitly taught in his own Algebra 2 textbook.)

Comment: Not a site for homework questions

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda actually there's no such formal policy. But if you want to suggest it, please post it on meta for voting.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on http://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a philosophical question, it's a riddle.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is a bad joke, because it's not a good puzzle. I'll offer my initial thoughts anyway.

A(ckermann) has written down some number x ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} in an envelope. Only he knows the referent of x, so B(eatrice) doesn't know in the beginning; neither does C(arl).

Now let's look at the sentences and how they update the information we have:

> 1) 1 < x < 9

After this statement, we know that x ∈ {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}.

> 2) (x = 2) → A didn’t write a number down.

We're told that A wrote a number down, so by *modus tollens*, we know that x is not equal to 2, so we've narrowed the set down to this: x ∈ {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}.

> 3) ¬∃<sub>x</sub> : [ (x = k) → ∀<sub>y</sub> : (y = k) ].

That says that there is no x such that if x is [the] number A wrote down, then everything is that number. Moving operators around a bit we get this equivalent statement:

> 3') ¬∃<sub>x</sub> : [ ¬(x = k) ∨ ∀<sub>y</sub> : (y = k) ],

which upon further manipulation turns out to be equivalent to these:

> 3') ∀<sub>x</sub> : ¬[ ¬(x = k) ∨ ∀<sub>y</sub> : (y = k) ].
>
> 3') ∀<sub>x</sub> : [ (x = k) ∧ ¬∀<sub>y</sub> : (y = k) ].
>
> 3') ∀<sub>x</sub> : [ (x = k) ∧ ∃<sub>y</sub> : ¬(y = k) ].
>
> 3') ∀<sub>x</sub> : [ (x = k) ∧ ∃<sub>y</sub> : (y ≠ k) ].

That last statement is a contradiction: it says that everything is k, but there is something that's not k. If my gloss of statement 3 is what was intended, then we can prove, on the basis of statements (1-3), by the *explosion principle*, that the number A has written down is 7. Oh, *and* that it is 3, and that it is 4, and so on. The point is that because (3) is a contradiction, anything follows from (1-3).

Comment: I would interpret 3) as "∃x : [ x is 'nothing'  ∨ and (x = k) → ∀y : (y = k)]".  That fits the specified wording better.  We already know something was written, "¬(nothing = k)", and thus the second part is redundant.  Thus, we can reword 3) as "The empty set exists".  We have no contradiction, but we also do not have enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: @user3294068 What does "x is 'nothing'" mean?

Comment: "is nothing" could be interpreted to mean "is the empty set".